# autoconf out of tree build with python

Tags: python, autoconf

My project uses autoconf, and the primary language is python.
Test are done from the toplevel Makefile.am:

```
SUBDIRS = src
distclean-local:
    rm -rf INSTALL `find -name Makefile.in -o -name '*.pyc'` aclocal.m4 autom4te.cache/ configure install-sh missing src/build

check:
    PYTHONPATH=src python -m unittest discover -p '*.py' -s tests
```

Installation is done from src/Makefile.am:

```
EXTRA_DIST = setup.py

clean:
    $(PYTHON) $(top_srcdir)/src/setup.py clean --all

install-exec-local:
    $(PYTHON) $(top_srcdir)/src/setup.py install --prefix $(DESTDIR)/$(prefix) --install-layout=deb
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    cp sinz.py $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/sinz
    chmod a+x $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/sinz
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/bash_completion.d/
    cp sinz.completion $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/bash_completion.d/sinz
```

I would like to be able to do the following, without creating .pyc files in the source directory.

```
autoreconf -i
cd /some/other/dir
/project/sourcedir/configure
make check
make install DESTDIR=/yet/another/dir
```

What should I change?

Comment: Note: Don't use that `distclean-local` rule. If you really want to remove stale autotools scripts (prior to rebuilding them), `make maintainer-clean` is safer.